# How to loop QListView item selection

Tags: qt, qlistview

How can I make QListView item selection loop from bottom item to top (by pressing navigation key, down) and from top item to bottom (by pressing navigation key, up)? Is there a flag to be defined or some other way? My listview is in IconMode I wanted the selection to go to next row's 1st item when I've reached the end of a row.

Thanks

Comment: you mean, you are talking about the gesture moment of listview?

Comment: no, its for 3rd edition non-touch symbian phones. all to do with selection of items using navigation keys. currently what happens is, say I have 3 items in a row once i reach the 3rd item a click on right arrow does nothing, i want it to come to 1st item of next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Default behavior provided by the list view for iconic mode.
in order to achieve your requirement, you need to handle it manually.

i.e you will be having the count of items in a row, once you reach the last item handle the right navigation key press event, then focus it back to the first element of the same row..

to get the navigation keypress event, either you install event filter or ovveride the keypress event function.

Comment: Okay :).. thought there would be some property setting which I could directly keep the selection happening.

Comment: probably, just check the documentation once else go ahead with the manual implementation..